# CPU Utilization is 60% when no requests for Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, cpu-usage

Our Linux server shows 60% CPU Utilization by TOMCAT. But there is no requests or no background process are running. It looks like some thing got struck and not releasing the CPU. 
Is there any way to find out which request or which object in Tomcat application causes it

**UPDATE**: Did Thread Profiling using new relic agent and identified one thread was always running though there is no requests for the server. We dig into this and had infinite loop burns more CPU, we fixed the infinite loop and works fine now

Comment: Does restarting tomcat resolve the problem? When do these spikes begin again? What have you deployed? Have you run a profiler yet?

Comment: Yes, Restarting resolves the problem. But It spikes again if we give load for 2 hours, but its not reducing even after a day. We have deployed only one Java application

Comment: Thanks reto, Did Thread Profiling using new relic agent and shows always one thread though the system is idle. When we dig into one infinite loop was there and burns the CPU